# performance comparison stringr--str_replace_all

Tags: performance-testing, str-replace, stringr

Just wondering if there will be performance differences in running `str_replace_all`.

For example:

```
text <- c("a","b", "c") 
str_replace_all(text, c("a", "b", "c"), c("d", "e", "f"))
```

and

```
str_replace_all(text, "a", "d")
str_replace_all(text, "b", "e")
str_replace_all(text, "c", "f")
```

Both get me the same result but I was wondering what would be faster if I was doing the same procedure for close to 200,000 documents and if each document file was longer?

Comment: As is almost always the case with performance questions, the answer is "it depends" and/or "don't worry about it until you see a problem". The real answer is "test it".

Answer (score 1):

It is evident you will have better performance with a single `str_replace_all` call since you do not have to change `text` value. See, when you need to call `str_replace_all` to change the `text` value, you need to re-assign the value each time you replace and that means additional overhead.

Here is a test with 3 functions: `f1` uses the first approach, `f2` uses the second and `f3` is just a "chained" version of `f2`:

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> text <- c("a", "b", "c")

> f1 <- function(text) { text=str_replace_all(text, "a", "d"); text = str_replace_all(text, "b", "e"); text=str_replace_all(text, "c", "f"); return(text) }
> f1(text)
[1] "d" "e" "f"
> f2 <- function(text) { return(str_replace_all(text, c("a", "b", "c"), c("d", "e", "f"))) }
> f2(text)
[1] "d" "e" "f"
> f3 <- function(text) { return(str_replace_all(str_replace_all(str_replace_all(text, "c", "f"), "b", "e"), "a", "d")) }
> f3(text)
[1] "d" "e" "f"
> test <- microbenchmark( f1(text), f2(text), f3(text), times = 50000 )
> test
Unit: microseconds
     expr     min      lq     mean  median      uq      max neval
 f1(text) 225.788 233.335 257.2998 239.673 262.313 25071.76 50000
 f2(text) 182.321 187.755 207.1858 191.980 210.393 24844.76 50000
 f3(text) 224.581 231.825 255.2167 237.863 259.898 24531.74 50000
```

With `times = 50000`, the functions were run 50,000 times and the *median* value, being the lowest with `f2`, together with *lower quartile* (lq) and *upper quartile* (uq) values,  proves that a single `str_replace_all` is the fastest. `autoplot(test)` (from `ggplot2` library) shows:
[image]

And finally, it is best to use [`stri_replace_all_fixed`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringi/versions/0.2-5/topics/stri_replace_all_fixed) from *stringi* package if you need to only replace literal strings. Then, here is the benchmark:

```
> library(stringi)
> f1 <- function(text) { text=stri_replace_all_fixed(text, "a", "d"); text = stri_replace_all_fixed(text, "b", "e"); text=stri_replace_all_fixed(text, "c", "f"); return(text) }
> f2 <- function(text) { return(stri_replace_all_fixed(text, c("a", "b", "c"), c("d", "e", "f"))) }
> f3 <- function(text) { return(stri_replace_all_fixed(stri_replace_all_fixed(stri_replace_all_fixed(text, "c", "f"), "b", "e"), "a", "d")) }
> test <- microbenchmark( f1(text), f2(text), f3(text), times = 50000 )
> test
Unit: microseconds
     expr   min    lq     mean median    uq       max neval cld
 f1(text) 7.547 7.849 9.197490  8.151 8.453  1008.800 50000   b
 f2(text) 3.321 3.623 4.420453  3.925 3.925  2053.821 50000  a 
 f3(text) 7.245 7.547 9.802766  7.849 8.151 50816.654 50000   b
```